# How do I get the web service to execute before return statement?

Tags: java, android, boolean, retrofit, return-value

I have a method that is returning a boolean value from a web service call.
Problem is it that it is is executing the return statement (returning a false value every time the method is called) then returning to the method and executing the web service call after (which gives a true value that is not being returned.

I have tried:

- Adding a finally clause
- Adding a conditional statement that has a value 0 if call hasn't been executed and 1 if it has
- I tried using new Thread() too but to no avail
- I also tried to see if it's anything I'm doing wrong at the call and all I did was use as the condition to an if statement

```js
public boolean remindTheUser(RemindTheUser remindTheUser) throws Exception {

  RequestObject request = Retrofit.getRetrofitInstance().create(RequestObject.class);

  final Call < JsonElement > jsonElementCall = request.callService(remindTheUser);

  jsonElementCall.enqueue(new Callback < JsonElement > () {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call < JsonElement > call, Response < JsonElement > response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        try {
          String responseString = response.body().getAsJsonObject().toString().trim();

          JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString);

          status = reader.getBoolean("status");

        } catch (JSONException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          throw ex;
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call < JsonElement > call, Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  });

  return status;
}
```

How do I get the web service to execute **THEN** return the status value

> status is a global variable

**EDITED**
My solution to try fix the error with suggestions from the comments is to do this:

```
try {
        RequestObject request = Retrofit.getRetrofitInstance().create(RequestObject.class);

        Call<JsonElement> call = request.callService(remindTheUser);
        JsonElement tasks = call.execute().body();

        //String responseString = tasks.body().getAsJsonObject().toString().trim();
        String responseString = tasks.getAsJsonObject().toString().trim();
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString);

        status = reader.getBoolean("status");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
    return status;
```

But I keep getting a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: You do not return from a method which have `Asynchronous` call . Do your stuff inside callback methods .Use a callback to notify.

Comment: @ADM let me try that

Comment: @ADM please check my update and help

Answer (score 0):

Use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()`. Then, make sure that you call `remindTheUser()` on a background thread.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: I tried it but im facing difficulty... i edited the question to show how i tried to use execute()

Comment: @ThapeloM: "But I keep getting a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" -- as I wrote, make sure that you call `remindTheUser()` on a background thread.